# How to show an array element of decreasing sequence changes its direction in javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript how to determine all the numbers at which an increasing or decreasing sequence changes its direction

For e.g

[23, 45, 21, 90 ,95 ,67, 30, 15 ,18]

answer

Output: 45 21 95 15

45 is first highest, 21 first lowest, 90 > 95 is first highest, 67 first highest, 30 < 15 <18 first lowest.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getSequenceChanges(array) {
  const result = [];
  let direction = '';

  array.forEach((element, index) => {
    const newDirection = element > array[index + 1] ? 'increase' : 'decrease';

    if (direction && direction !== newDirection && index < array.length - 1) {
      result.push(element);
    }

    direction = newDirection;
  });

  return result;
}

const array = [23, 45, 21, 90, 95, 67, 30, 15, 18];
console.log(getSequenceChanges(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if sign of the delta of the value and previous is the same as for the next value.

```js
var data = [23, 45, 21, 90, 95, 67, 30, 15, 18],
    result = data.filter((v, i, { [i - 1]: l, [i + 1]: r }) =>
        Math.sign(l - v) === Math.sign(r - v)
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this using `filter` method and `thisArg` param to store the last condition result.

```js
const data = [23, 45, 21, 90, 95, 67, 30, 15, 18]

const result = data.filter(function(e, i, a) {
  const next = a[i + 1], last = this.seq
  this.seq = next > e
  return (last === null || !next) ? false : last !== next > e
}, {seq: null})

console.log(result)
```